# Calculations concerning the Gudermannian function

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, special-functions

I did calculations to get some simple expressions involving the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) $$\text{gd}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\cosh t}.$$

I don't sure if these statements are rights, but I know how do the calculations, thus my mistake should be a little detail.

> **Question 1.** One has $$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}\int_0^xe^t\text{gd}(t)dt=\frac{\pi}{2},$$ and defining $$F(x)=\int_0^xe^t\text{gd}(t)dt,$$ then $$F''(x)-F'(x)=e^x(\text{gd}(x))'.$$
> **Are rights these claims? Only is required a yes, or where was my mistake.**

And for the following, I know that there is a relationship satisfied by the Gudermannian function and the **inverse tangent function** (see in previous link to **Wikipedia**), then when I was exploring the calculation of the following integral with **Wolfram Alpha** $$\int_0^1\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\text{gd}(x)\right)dx$$ I've asked to me

> **Question 2.** Can you provide us hints to calculate $$\int_0^1 \arctan(e^x)dx?$$

Here is the code for previous [online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)

> int arctan(e^x) dx, from x=0 to x=1
>
> int arctan(e^x) dx

**Many thanks.**

Comment: i have found $$-C+\frac{1}{2} i (\text{Li}_2(-i e)-\text{Li}_2(i e))$$

Comment: C is the Catalan-constant and LI the polylog-function

Comment: Yes I compute it with previous code, but I don't know how calculate this, if it is a well known identity, you can add only some hints: how one can start to explore and deduce the statement? Very thanks much @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to question 2. To evaluate

\begin{equation}
I = \int\limits_{0}^{1} \tan^{-1}(\mathrm{e}^{x}) \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
we begin by expressing the [inverse tangent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html) as logarithms:
\begin{equation}
\tan^{-1}(z) = \frac{i}{2} [\ln(1-iz) - \ln(1+iz)]
\end{equation}
thus our integral becomes
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{i}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{1} \left(\ln(1-i\mathrm{e}^{x}) - \ln(1+i\mathrm{e}^{x}) \right) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{i}{2} (I_{1} + I_{2})
\end{align}

To evaluate $I_{1}$ we make the substitution $z = i\mathrm{e}^{x}$
\begin{align}
I_{1} &= \int\limits_{0}^{1} \ln(1-ie^{x}) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int\limits_{i}^{i\mathrm{e}} \frac{\ln(1-z)}{z} \mathrm{d}z \\
&= \int\limits_{0}^{i\mathrm{e}} \frac{\ln(1-z)}{z} \mathrm{d}z - \int\limits_{0}^{i} \frac{\ln(1-z)}{z} \mathrm{d}z\\
&= \mathrm{Li}_{2}(i) - \mathrm{Li}_{2}(i\mathrm{e}) \\
&= i\mathrm{G} - \frac{\pi^{2}}{48} - \mathrm{Li}_{2}(i\mathrm{e})
\end{align}

To evaluate $I_{2}$ we make the substitution $-z = i\mathrm{e}^{x}$
\begin{align}
I_{2} &= \int\limits_{0}^{1} \ln(1+ie^{x}) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int\limits_{-i}^{-i\mathrm{e}} \frac{\ln(1-z)}{z} \mathrm{d}z \\
&= \int\limits_{0}^{-i\mathrm{e}} \frac{\ln(1-z)}{z} \mathrm{d}z - \int\limits_{0}^{-i} \frac{\ln(1-z)}{z} \mathrm{d}z\\
&= \mathrm{Li}_{2}(-i\mathrm{e}) - \mathrm{Li}_{2}(-i) \\
&= \mathrm{Li}_{2}(-i\mathrm{e}) - \left(-i\mathrm{G} - \frac{\pi^{2}}{48} \right)
\end{align}

Putting the pieces together, we obtain our final result
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{i}{2} (I_{1} + I_{2}) \\
&= \frac{i}{2} [\mathrm{Li}_{2}(-i\mathrm{e}) - \mathrm{Li}_{2}(i\mathrm{e})] - \mathrm{G} \\
&= \int\limits_{0}^{1} \tan^{-1}(\mathrm{e}^{x}) \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}

Notes:

1. $\mathrm{G}$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)
2. $\mathrm{Li}_{2}(z)$ is the [dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html).
3. Expressions for $\mathrm{Li}_{2}(\pm i)$ can be found [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/catalan/catalan.htm).

Comment: Very thanks much for your answer.